# Order tracking (angular resampling) in vibration signal

Tags: angular, signals, signal-processing, tracking, vibration

I'm trying to implement in python an order tracking to a vibration signal from a gearbox, and dont have idea about how to do it. Anyone have an example or a tutorial to help me? We have a tachometer signal to use as reference. The pictures bellow show the angular resampling tool.

[Angular resampling 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZH41.png)

[Angular resampling 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz6Oq.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you find a implementation?

Comment: I might be one year too late. But what exactly are you asking? You record one time-trace acceleration vs time and one time-trace rotational speed vs time. If you combine both you have acceleration vs rotational speed. That's what you want, right?
If you want to use the rotational speed to perform order filtering of your acceleration data the Vold-Kalman filter should help you achieve that.